# Making a python loop faster

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, for-loop

Can this little routine be made faster? With the elif's it makes a comprehension get out of hand, but maybe I haven't tried it the right way.

```
def cleanup(s):
    strng = ''
    good = ['\t', '\r', '\n']
    for char in s:        
        if unicodedata.category(char)[0]!="C":
            strng += char
        elif char in good:
            strng += char
        elif char not in good:
            strng += ' '
    return strng
```

Comment: At least you could speed up alot by change `elif char not in good:` to `else:`. If you want someone to maybe find a better way then add example `string`, `unicodedata.category` and explain more what you are doing.

Comment: In general, `some_string += some_other_string` in a loop will be slow. It has quadratic complexity (although the interpreter will try to optimize it), however, you should refractor it to use a `list` with `.append` then `''.join` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your task correctly, you want to replace all *unicode control characters* with spaces **except** `\t`, `\n` and `\r`.

Here's how to do this more efficiently with regular expressions instead of loops.

```
import re

# make a string of all unicode control characters 
# EXCEPT \t - chr(9), \n - chr(10) and \r - chr(13)
control_chars = ''.join(map(unichr, range(0,9) + \
                            range(11,13) + \
                            range(14,32) + \
                            range(127,160)))

# build your regular expression
cc_regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(control_chars))

def cleanup(s):
    # substitute all control characters in the regex 
    # with spaces and return the new string
    return cc_regex.sub(' ', s)
```

You can control which characters to include or exclude by manipulating the ranges that make up the `control_chars` variable.  Refer to the [List of Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters).

**EDIT**:  *Timing results.*

Just out of curiosity I ran some timing tests to see which of the three current methods are fastest.

I made three methods named `cleanup_op(s)` that was a copy of the OP's code; `cleanup_loop(s)` which is Cristian Ciupitu's answer; `cleanup_regex(s)` which is my code.

Here's what I ran:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

sample = u"this is a string with some characters and \n new lines and \t tabs and \v and other stuff"*1000

start = timer();cleanup_op(sample);end = timer();print end-start
start = timer();cleanup_loop(sample);end = timer();print end-start
start = timer();cleanup_regex(sample);end = timer();print end-start
```

The results:

cleanup_op finished in about **1.1 seconds**

cleanup_loop finished in about **0.02 seconds**

cleanup_regex finished in about **0.004 seconds**

So, either one of the answers is a significant improvement over the original code.  I think @CristianCiupitu gives a more elegant and pythonic answer while regex is still faster.

Comment: Even if [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) has a small cache of the compiled patterns, it's probably best to move the compilation of the regulation expression outside the `cleanup` function, so that this step is not done at every call.

Comment: Also if you want to do the same thing as OP, `cc_regex.sub('', s)` should be replaced with `cc_regex.sub(' ', s)` (those special characters are converted to spaces, not removed).

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Sure, sounds good.  I fixed the answer to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: Your code deals only with control characters from categories __C0__ and __C1__. You're missing __Cf__ (format control character), __Cs__ (surrogate code point), __Co__ (private-use character) and __Cn__ (reserved unassigned code point or a noncharacter).

Comment: I run some [%timeit](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) benchmarks too on an Intel i7-3770 CPU for 3800 chars string (200 had to be replaced). I changed my code to use the same limited control characters set as yours. On python2-2.7.14-10.fc27.x86_64 the regex code takes 69.4 µs and the translation code 414 µs. On python3-3.6.5-1.fc27.x86_64 the results were 56 µs ± 186 ns and 4.32 µs ± 4.62 ns.

Comment: Brilliant!! You get 1 million billion points!! Seriously, thank you, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to convert all the Unicode control characters to space, except the *tab*, *carriage return* and *new line*. You can use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for this:

```
good = map(ord, '\t\r\n')
TBL_CONTROL_TO_SPACE = {
    i: u' '
    for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode)
    if unicodedata.category(unichr(i))[0] == "C" and i not in good
}

def cleanup(s):
    return s.translate(TBL_CONTROL_TO_SPACE)
```